# How to use 3rd party AngularJS (1.6) module (angular-translate) in Angular (2 or 4)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-translate, angular-upgrade

### The case

I am in the process of upgrading an AngularJS (i.e. Angular 1.6) application to Angular (i.e. Angular 4.1.3). I chose to do the incremental upgrade so currently both AngularJS and Angular are bootstrapped and running. So far so good, but: One of the AngularJS services that should be rewritten to Angular relies on a well known service `$translate` which is part of the 3rd party AngularJS (read Angular 1) module [pascalprecht.translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/). In other words, `$translate` service is injected to `MyService` which should become an Angular (read Angular 4) service.

`MyService` (stripped down) looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    // Here comes the injection (how to do it?).
    constructor(private $translate: $translate) {

    }

    foo() {
        // Use the service
        this.$translate('HELLO_WORLD');
    }
}
```

It is located within `MyModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from './my.service';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MyService
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

### The problem

Now, how can I inject `$translate` into `MyService` when `MyService` resides within an Angular module while `$translate` is part of a 3rd party AngularJS module?

I know how to inject an AngularJS service into an Angular service if the AngularJS service is located within the same module (or at least the module is part of my own solution). It is explained in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular). Is there any way to handle a 3rd party service? Do I need to register that service within `MyModule`'s providers?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from './my.service';

// How this line should look line then?
import { $translate } from 'node_modules/angular-translate/...';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MyService,
        $translate
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

Or am I trying to achieve impossible?

Comment: Have a look https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate

Comment: @UshmaJoshi, thx for the suggestion but that is not an option. I want to use the original one. Need to make a proof it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after a few hours of struggling I've finally found the solution. Here it is:

### Upgrade the 3rd party service

First of all, follow the [Angular's official guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular) and upgrade the provider of the 3rd party service - `$translate`. Like this:

**ajs-upgraded-providers.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import 'angular-translate';

// Variable 'i' holds the standard AngularJS injector
export function $translateFactory(i: any) {
    return i.get('$translate');
};

// There is no class representing the good old $translate service so we have
// a non-class dependency. Therefore we use an InjectionToken (Angular 4) or
// OpaqueToken (Angular 2).
export let $translate = new InjectionToken('$translate');

// Finally create the upgraded provider
export const $translateProvider = { 
    provide: $translate,
    useFactory: $translateFactory,
    deps: ['$injector']
};
```

One thing to notice, the `$translate` service might be dependent on other old AngularJS services like (in my case) `$translateStaticFilesLoader` or `$translateMessageFormatInterpolation`. If this is also your case, be sure to extend the code above and make upgraded providers for those services as well (keep them in the same file).

### Make sure the `import` statement works

The `angular-translate` is installed as a node module so the statement

```
import 'angular-translate';
```

works just fine if your `tsconfig.json` is set up to use `moduleResolution: "node"`.

Then, of course, you need to ensure that the `import` statement will work even after the code is transpiled from TypeScript to ES5 (or whichever target you use) and picked up by a module loader (SystemJS in my case).

Notice that we imported the `angular-translate` script without getting anything from it, just to [cause side effects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only). Basically, the import ensures that the script containing the desired service `$translate` is simply executed and registers `$translate` service for the AngularJS $injector.

### Register the upgraded provider in Angular module

Now ensure that the new upgraded provider of `$translate` service is registered among other providers of `MyModule`.

**my.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from './my.service';
import { $translateProvider } from './ajs-upgraded-providers';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MyService,
        $translateProvider
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

### Use it

Finally, use the `$translate` service in `MyService`.

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { $translate } from './ajs-upgraded-providers';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    // Notice the usage of InjectionToken
    constructor(@Inject($translate) private $translate: any) {
    }

    foo() {
        this.$translate('hello.world').then((translation: string) => {
            console.log(translation);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. Also how can we use translate directive or filter in Angular 2 component and then downgrade it to angularjs component?